# ggplot show the value rounded to one decimal place above the bar chart

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart, rounding

I want to round the values above the bar chart to one decimal place. For example 14 should be 1.5 and not 1.52977.

[This is how the bar chart looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd6X2.png)

This is my code:

```
CPUE1 <- CPUE
CPUE1$Strecke <- factor (CPUE1$Strecke, levels = c('30/31', '14', '12', '10','1c','1bc', '1b'))

ggplot(CPUE1, aes(x= Strecke, y= CPUE, fill = Strecke ))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = 'dodge')+
  theme_minimal()+
  geom_text (aes (label = CPUE), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)+
  scale_fill_manual (values = 
                       c("12" = "green", "10"= "green",
                         "1c" = "green", "14"= "red",
                         "1b"= "red","1bc"= "red","30/31" = "red"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `round` to your `geom_text`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~Strecke, ~CPUE,
  "1b", 1.333,
  "1c", 1.222,
  "1b", 2.666,
  "1c", 2.777
) |>
  mutate(Strecke = factor(Strecke)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Strecke, CPUE, fill = Strecke)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(CPUE, 1)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1b" = "red", "1c" = "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>